# Escrever cada passo do cálculo de um fatorial

Tags: javascript, html, for, fatorial

Tenho um pedaço de código que calcula o fatorial de um número em JavaScript, porém queria que ele retornasse os passos de cada cálculo, ex:

> 3! = 1x2x3 = 6

Segue o código que fiz. Tentei "printar" decrementando a variável, mas não tenho a certeza do que estou fazendo.

```js
var fatorial=1;
var num=parseInt(prompt("Digite um número: "));

for(var x=1; x<=num; x++)
{
  fatorial=fatorial*x;
}

document.write(num+"! = "+num+"x"+(num--)+"="+fatorial);
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Para que serve um laço? Para **repetir passos**, certo?

É dentro dele que você calcula cada passo do fatorial, certo?

Depois que termina os passos você está mandando imprimir o resultado final, mas você quer **imprimir cada passo**!

Deu para entender onde tem que colocar a impressão? Se não, comece ler esta resposta de novo desde o começo, agora com mais atenção.

Obviamente que deve formatar como deseja, escolher o que deverá ser impresso. Pode ser que seja útil ter uma impressão inicial antes de começar os passos. E ainda precisará da impressão do resultado final. Faça testes.

Eu poderia ter dado a resposta pronta, mas acho que assim vai aprender melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Para retornar os passos de cada calculo, concateno em uma string a cada calculo realizado fincando dessa forma:

```js
var fatorial=1;
var explicaFator = '';
var num=parseInt(prompt("Digite um número: "));
for(var x=1; x<=num; x++)
{
    fatorial=fatorial*x;
    if(explicaFator != ''){
      explicaFator += 'x';
    }
    explicaFator += x;
    
}
document.write(num+"! = "+explicaFator+" = "+fatorial);
```